# Most efficient structure for cloud functions in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is there a performance difference between the following two options for real-time database triggered functions?:

1. One cloud function that listens to all subnodes and decides what to execute based on the path
2. An entirely separate cloud function for each subnode.

This is assuming total number of function executions stays equal.

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple events happening at the same time, it may be a problem (from https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec):

> Cloud Functions may start multiple function instances to scale your
>   function up to meet the current load. These instances run in parallel,
>   which results in having more than one parallel function execution.
>
> However, each function instance handles only one concurrent request at
>   a time. This means while your code is processing one request, there is
>   no possibility of a second request being routed to the same function
>   instance, and the original request can use the full amount of
>   resources (CPU and memory) that you requested.

Adding to this, the logic for separate cloud functions should be a lot simpler than having one monolithic function checking for each trigger.

Comment: Maybe I'm not interpreting this correctly, but not seeing how this would be a problem as if the functions were separate functions, they would be different instances for each request as well. Unless there's a quota for each function name?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified better, my understanding is that performance-wise, one big cloud function should be slower (it'll need to go through the decision logic based on each event) vs multiple cloud functions where the decision logic is already there. If you have 99 events that don't get triggered a lot, but 1 event that does, then I guess one big cloud function becomes wasteful?

Comment: I see, though my decision logic is not complicated, as it just takes the path name and routes it to the right file, which then requires the correct packages. Just wasn't sure if there was something critically bigger going on that would warrant the time of switching back to separate functions. I had merged them all in one when we were on the Spark plan, so that we could deploy the function with one line of code.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by deploying the function with one line of code? Is that just `firebase deploy --only functions`?

Comment: now that we're on blaze plan, yes, but on spark plan, it would not let us deploy many functions at once, so we had to do them in batches, and putting many (not all) of our functions together into 1 function helped us save time with deployments